# How to Write Sql Query to show total number of leaveDays per months after calculating date difference between startDate and endDate

Tags: postgresql

There is Leave Table.It has two columns **start-date**,**end-date**.I need to show **total Number of Leave Days Per Month**. At first I have to calculate **totalNumberOfLeave** just like:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Person</th> 
        <th>startDate</th>
        <th>endDate</th>
        <th>totalNumberOfLeave</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>PersonA</td>
        <td>2016-08-10</td>
        <td>2016-08-12</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>PersonB</td>
        <td>2016-08-31</td>
        <td>2016-09-03</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>PersonC</td>
        <td>2016-08-30</td>
        <td>2016-09-06</td>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

After calculating **TotalNumberOfLeave**,Then I need to show totalNumberOfLeave Per Month just like

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th>NumberOfLeave</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

(Person A takes 2016-08-10,2016-08-11,2016-08-12 as Leave,Person B takes 2016-08-31 as Leave,PersonC takes 2016-08-30,2016-08-31 as Leave in August)

How should I write for showing **totalNumberOfLeave Per Month**?
DB I use is **Postgresql9.3**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    DATE_PART('MONTH',A.ATTENDANCEDATE) AS MONTH, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN (A.FULLDAY = '1') THEN 1 ELSE 0.5 END ) AS DURATION
FROM
    (
    SELECT GENERATE_SERIES(START_DATE,END_DATE, '1 DAY'::INTERVAL) AS ATTENDANCEDATE, IS_FULLDAY AS FULLDAY
    FROM LEAVE_TAKEN
    ) AS A
GROUP BY 
    DATE_PART('MONTH',A.ATTENDANCEDATE)
ORDER BY
    DATE_PART('MONTH',A.ATTENDANCEDATE);
```